# Athena table partition by date in unix timestamp format

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

I have an S3 bucket with files grouped according to its creation date and the date is in unix timestamp form as show below. I have previously worked with partition by date with following settings:

```
  'projection.partition_date.format'='yyyy-MM-dd', 
  'projection.partition_date.range'='2020-07-01,2025-12-31', 
  'projection.partition_date.type'='date',
```

How can I create a new table with different settings to support the unix timestamp type of partition?

[image]

Comment: you need to create a new table with new partition. Then insert into new table from old table and change data type and format too. And then drop old table

Comment: That’s my exact question, in the new table, how do I partition by Unix timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

1. create an empty table -

```
CREATE TABLE mynewtable(    
  key string,   
  id BIGINT,
  col3 string
  ) 
PARTITIONED BY (unix_timestamp_partcol BIGINT)   ; -- make a partition col with data type INT because unix timestamp produces bigint data
```

2. insert from old tabel into new table converting to correct format.

```
insert into mynewtable partition(unix_timestamp_partcol)
select 
key,id,col3,
unix_timestamp(partition_col_in_date_format,'yyyy-MM-dd')) as unix_timestamp_partcol -- convert existing column data into unix timestamp format
from myoldtable;
```

3. drop table myoldtable;

set below properties ifyou dint already

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;  
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm more looking into a solution to build a table on top of existing s3 storage location without data migration. If it's not possible, appreciate your confirmation

Comment: not possible without data movement because you are restructuring actual folder structure which is impossible without delete and recreate.